# 【Railsチュートリアル】LoadError: cannot load such file -- test_helperとなりパスできません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

現在、Railsチュートリアル第５章５．４をやっています。
（http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/filling_in_the_layout?version=4.2#cha-filling_in_the_layout）

> リスト5.28により、newアクションを持つUsersコントローラ(リスト5.30)と、スタブのユーザービューを作成します(リスト5.31)。このとき、新しいUserページ用の小さなテスト
>   (リスト5.32) も生成されていて、この時点ではパスするはずです。

とあるのですが、Usersコントローラーを生成した後、

```
$bundle exec rake test
```

を入力すると、

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- test_helper
/Users/rails-projects/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/rails-projects/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

となり、テストが実行できません。

どのように解決したら良いのでしょうか？

(追記）
test/test_helper.rbが無かったので、作成してから実行すると、
何も起こらずに、終わってしまいます。

fkenta:sample_app kentaf$ bundle exec rake test
　　　fkenta:sample_app kentaf$

Comment: test/test_helper.rb は存在していますか？ (質問を編集して書き足してください)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーの示すとおりにファイルが存在しないとすると、何かの手違いでtest/test_helper.rbを消してしまったのでしょう。

しかるべき内容が必要なので、適当に別アプリケーションを作ってそこからコピーしてくるか、一つ上のディレクトリでもう一度`rails new appname`を実行してファイルを再作成するかしてください。`rails new`する場合、作成後更新したファイルは「conflictしてるので上書きするか」と聞いてきますので必ず[n]で答えてください。